# scanner.findWithinHorizon gives incorrect results

Tags: java, regex

To scan a file for certain pattern i am using scanner.findWithinHorizon, it gives incorrect results.
Here is what i have done :

```
content = readFile(<filepath>, Charset.forName( "utf-8"));
Pattern pattern =   Pattern.compile(wordtoMatch ,Pattern.MULTILINE);
while ((s !=null) && (null != s.findWithinHorizon(pattern,0) )) {

    MatchResult mr = s.match();


     System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", mr.group(),
             mr.start(), mr.end());
}
```

Results:

```
 Word found: gets( at index 5991 to 5996.
    .......

    Word found: gets( at index 8170 to 8175.

    Word found: gets( at index 8180 to 8185.

    Word found: gets( at index 3 to 8.
```

**----------->It is restarting here It should have continued like 8188**

```
    Word found: gets( at index 11 to 16.

   .....
    Word found: gets( at index 18765 to 18770.

    Word found: gets( at index 18774 to 18779.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure what is causing this any pointers would be really helpful.

I have checked IOException and its null

Comment: use `Scanner.next(Pattern)` instead as you don't require the limit that `Scanner.findWithinHorizon()` provides

Comment: @vandale: They're not equivalent.  `next(Pattern)` expects the pattern to match right after the next delimiter (which is whitespace by default).  `findWithinHorizon(Pattern,0)` ignores delimiters and scans as far ahead as necessary to find the next match.  In fact, it works just like `Matcher.find()`, except it works on streams as well as on strings.

Comment: I've never run into that before, but apparently it's a known quirk, as explained in the Q/A I linked to.  `start()` and `end()` don't really have any meaning when you're matching on a stream.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I was able to solve issue by converting inputstream to string and used Matcher.